# How to play Music file J2m from database?

Tags: file, mobile, java-me

I'm trying to play wav file from database .I recuparate blob file with php file.
This code works with video file if we replace inputStream with DataInputStream:

public void playAudio() {

```
    try {
        ContentConnection connection = (ContentConnection)Connector.open("http://localhost/P/getXmlMusic.php");
      InputStream iStrm = connection.openInputStream();         

        player = Manager.createPlayer(iStrm,"audio/x-wav");
        player.addPlayerListener(this);
        player.setLoopCount(4);
        player.prefetch();
        player.realize();
        player.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Error : Failed to realize Player: Malformed wave media: expected 'RIFF'

NB : I can play the same file locally.So the file is okey!

Comment: Did you remember to add a `header()` in your PHP file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The valid WAV file [should be started with "RIFF" string](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/).

**expected 'RIFF'** means that RIFF string isn't found in the start of the WAV file. So it seems that the retrieved stream from server is not a valid WAV file.

I suggest you to try playing the original WAV file from your device's (locally).
Change your code a bit to access the WAV using FileConnection API, or embed it directly inside the jar then read it using `getResourceAsStream`.

If the same error still persist, then the WAV file is invalid / not-standard, and Java API inside your device won't able to play it.

If the error is gone, then the mistake is in the server-side code. Ensure you have performed all operations correctly : filling database with wav file, read the blob from database, and forward it to client.